# htaccess rewrite rule without access to direct file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works fine. e.g. when entering `localhost/file` it acts as if it was `localhost/index.php?route=file`

My problem however is that the server is set to serve files without the need to type `.php` as file extension. So when I access `localhost/login`, instead of doing `localhost/index.php?route=login`, it serves me the file `login.php` directly. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2):

Simply disable `MultiViews` option.

Replace your current code by this one

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I just found the solution on the internet before reading your answer. But I'll consider as the answer anyway, for those coming across the question.
My research before asking hadn't given me a solution.